# How to fix WrongInputException in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, exception, webservice-client

I want to use a SOAP web service prepared by another team, used internally in my new REST API prepared in ASP.NET Core. My web service client code was scaffolded with [WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide). I cleaned up code (e.g. I changed property and method names) according to my team's naming convention.

When I send requests by my new REST API, I received `WrongInputException`. I checked all the parameters from an example request, all of them are in the same place in my C# code consuming scaffolded client.

I don't know what message exactly is sent by my new REST API.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the main cause of the described behavior and `WrongInputException` was [premature refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646653/premature-refactoring). **I changed the names of properties in the web service client without knowledge of the consequences.**

E.g. if the element in the request body is `objectRefNum`, then I cannot simply change the related property in the scaffolded service reference class, because - without extra configuration - that name is copied with the same letter case to the request body of the SOAP envelope. **The SOAP envelope should be encoded in the case-sensitive mode.**

To trace the raw request body send by my new REST API in ASP.NET Core, I followed instructions from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54909222/3734141).

(Note, BTW, that kind of error (applying inappropriate letter case) could be handled by IDE, at least as a warning, but it is not, so: we need to be careful when we make refactoring, even if we have unit tests covering all the paths, and even if we use semantic renaming supported by IDE.)